# Fat Free Framework change $f3 variable name

Tags: php, global-variables, fat-free-framework

For those who know FatFree Framework, you are used to see this variable `$f3`. I want to change it to some other name more intuitive like `$this` or `$app`, and although I know that it's possible, what are the counter parts of doing that?

For example, this code:

```
<?php

$f3=require('lib/base.php');

$f3->set('DEBUG',1);
if ((float)PCRE_VERSION<7.9)
    trigger_error('PCRE version is out of date');

$f3->config('config.ini');
```

Would be:

```
<?php

$app=require('lib/base.php');

$app->set('DEBUG',1);
if ((float)PCRE_VERSION<7.9)
    trigger_error('PCRE version is out of date');

$app->config('config.ini');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's absolutely no counterpart of doing so. Here, `$f3` is a local PHP variable, which can be renamed to whatever you like, as long as you follow the usual rules for [PHP variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php).

Especially, PHP won't allow you to rename it to `$this`, which is a reserved keyword.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @xfra35, I change the name of the variable and didn't get any problem yet.